# Why does checkValidity or reportValidity triger automatic submit of a form in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, constraint-validation-api

Consider the following code:

```
$("button[type='submit']").click(function(e){ 
  if($(this).closest("form").checkValidity()) {
    $(this).closest("form").reportValidity();
  }   
  e.preventDefault();   
  alert("Never happens!!!");   
});
```

If the input data is valid and then I press the submit button, the php form is submitted without letting `e.preventDefault();` and `alert("Never happens!!!");` to get executed. I suspect this happens because `checkValidity` and `reportValidity` return `true`, which acts as a `return true;` statement.

Consider this code:

```
$("button[type='submit']").click(function(e){         
  e.preventDefault();   
  alert("Does happen!!!");   
});
```

This time I see the alert, meaning `preventDefault` stopped the form from being submitted. What is strange to me even if `checkValidity` and `reportValidity` return `true`, how can they act as return statement for the jquery click function?

It should be noted that the following approach doesn't work either:

```
$("button[type='submit']").click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  if($(this).closest("form").checkValidity()) {
    $(this).closest("form").reportValidity();
  }          
  alert("Never happens!!!");   
});
```

I think `preventDefault` prevents `checkValidity` and `reportValidity` to work properly and forces them to return `false`, which somehow acts as `return false;` statement causing the `alert` to not get executed.

Another possible explanation could be that calling either `checkValidity` or `reportValidity` causes the form to get submitted. I don't know why would that be the case.

Please give an explanation with reference to official documentation.

Comment: My guess is that your script breaks. For instance if the script for the validation plugin fails to load, calling `$(this).closest("form").checkValidity()` will result in an error and prevent any further script commands from executing. This explains why you never see the alert. Did you check your browser console for error messages?

Comment: @ChrisG Ahhh. such as naïve mistake... I am supposed to use `$(this).closest("form")[0]`.  I am not using any plugin, rather the native html5 validation api.

Answer (score 2):

`checkValidity()` and `reportValidity()` are not methods of a jQuery object. You need to call them on the underlying `form` Element object instead.

It also seems from the context that the logic in the `if` condition needs to be inverted so that the `reportValidity()` is called only when the form is *invalid* - along with the `e.preventDefault()` to stop the actual form submission.

```js
$("button[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
  let form = $(this).closest('form').get(0);
  if (!form.checkValidity()) {
    form.reportValidity();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  console.log("Will always happen");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="" required />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

That being said, your JS code is completely redundant as you get this exact behaviour for free by default when you apply the `required` attribute to any control within the form:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="" required />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Actually I am intentionally not allowing submit even for correct input, I rather show another bootstrap modal for further conditional checks. I show the modal only when the primary input is valid. The whole question is just a silly mistake.

Comment: In which case the answer above still works, you can simply move the `preventDefault()` outside the `if`

Comment: I didn't nee to use both `reportValidity` and `checkValidity` togther. `form.reportValidity();` just return `false` or `true` which does nothing in the current logic. In my actual code I ended up using `if(!$(this).closest("form")[0].reportValidity()) {        
        $(this).submit();
      } ` This way I can see the browser default tooltips and later I use `preventDefault` to make sure the form doesn't get submitted with correct input.